# Javascript/jquery how to remove one character after each occurrence with in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have a string similar to below.  I want to remove the characters after each occurrence of the word "name".  How can I get the desired result.

Current string:

```
var str = "name0, name1, name2, name3, name4 and that will be all";
```

Desired Result:

```
var str = "name, name, name, name, name and that will be all";
```

Thanks ahead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex with the `String.replace` function:

```
var str = "name0, name1, name2";
str = str.replace(/name./g, 'name');
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
str = str.replace(/\b(name)\w\b/g, '$1');
```

I made two assumptions here: first, you wouldn't want to replace words like `surname0`; second, you won't need to remove comma (or similar symbols) in `name,`.

If you need to replace *all* the alphanumeric symbols following `name` (or some fixed word), just add `+` modifier, like this:

```
str = str.replace(/\b(name)\w+/g, '$1');
```

Note that you won't need second `\b` here: when `\w+` match is done, clearly there's either `\W` symbol - or end of the string.

Comment: Nicely done, but I think `\w\b` should be `\w+\b` since OP says `I want to remove the characters after each occurrence`

Comment: Then `\w+` will be enough actually, as where `\w+` ends, `\b` definitely follows. )

Comment: Thanks to you, too; actually, you gave a very good point about the true need of the OP. )